# Proving vector projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

For nonzero vectors, how do you prove the following?

- $$\|u\|^2 = \|\text{projection of $u$ onto $v$}\|^2 + \|u - \text{projection of $u$ onto $v$}\|^2$$

I think what we need to do is split up the latter part into two, but can't we only do this if the vector "$u$" and the vector projection onto "$v$" are orthogonal?  How do I go about proving this?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Think Pythagoras: the vectors $\mathrm{proj}_{\vec v}(\vec u)$ and $\vec u - \mathrm{proj}_{\vec v}(\vec u)$ are orthogonal, so the triangle whose vertices are $\vec 0$, $\vec u$ and $\mathrm{proj}_{\vec v}(\vec u)$ forms a right-angled triangle.

To verify that $\mathrm{proj}_{\vec v}(\vec u)$ and $\vec u - \mathrm{proj}_{\vec v}(\vec u)$ are orthogonal, note that
$$\mathrm{proj}_{\vec v}(\vec u) = \frac{\vec u \cdot \vec v}{\vec v \cdot \vec v} \vec v$$
meaning that
$$\mathrm{proj}_{\vec v}(\vec u) \cdot (\vec u - \mathrm{proj}_{\vec v}(\vec u)) = \left( \frac{\vec u \cdot \vec v}{\vec v \cdot \vec v} \vec v\ \cdot\ (\vec u - \frac{\vec u \cdot \vec v}{\vec v \cdot \vec v} \vec v)\right)\ \underbrace{=\ \cdots\ =}_{\text{you do this bit}}\ 0$$

Comment: I realize this but still can't understand how to prove it. @Clive Newstead

Comment: I've put in some more details.

Comment: Is showing that the two are orthogonal to each other, and pythagoras thus can be used, enough of a proof?  Please explain further. @Clive Newstead

Comment: @user141820: That depends on what results you are allowed to use. If not, it doesn't matter: the result you prove by following my hint allows you to simplify an expression for $$\lVert \mathrm{proj}_{\vec v}(\vec u) \rVert^2 + \lVert \vec u - \mathrm{proj}_{\vec v}(\vec u) \rVert^2$$ in terms of dot products. (Namely, use $\lVert \vec a \rVert^2 = \vec a \cdot \vec a$ on both terms and do the algebra.) You should end up with $\vec u \cdot \vec u$, which is equal to $\lVert \vec u \rVert^2$.